# Hiding items in the Content Editor for certain users / roles

Tags: content-editor, security

The content editors want to divide up their roles so that some editors of the site only have access to edit and change a certain area of the site (e.g. `/news` and all its descendants). These editors would belong to a particular role, e.g. `News Editor`. They would like it to be as easy as possible for them, so in the Content Editor they *would only see the pages that relate to them*.

To do this I have tried using item security to remove their Read access to the other pages of the site. However now when those users try to preview the site, it doesn't look right or it breaks because renderings aren't able to read the items.

I still want them to be able to preview the site as if they were a real user, so they may still need Read access to these items for that to work. Can I just restrict their view of items in the Content Editor, but have the site still function correctly?

I am aware I can remove their Write access and they would then be prevented from editing certain items and the site would still work for them, however that does not solve this problem.

Comment: The preview should browse the site in the extranet/anonymous user to mimic how an end user would see the site. So you shouldn't have any security issues there. How are they previewing the site?

Comment: How would you mark an item as hidden for one user role and a different item as hidden for another user role? I tried restricting read access but then the users get null reference errors when trying to browse the pages in preview mode.

Answer (score 8):

You could mark those items as hidden - regular users don't see hidden items by default (and you can disable option to show them as well)

[image: Show/hide hidden items]

You can set it on the item or on the template's standard values. Just search for a `Hidden` field in the `Appearance` section.

[image: Hidden field]

Comment: Worth expanding upon, how they can mark items as hidden?

Comment: It's a habbit from stackoverflow - answer first and the add the details :) But thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Regular users of a particular role would still need to see these items, I'll edit my question to make this more clear.

Comment: Any comments why downvoting?

Comment: @SzymonKuzniak there is an option for users to see hidden items ... inside Content Editor > top left red menu bar > Application options > Hidden items. Can this be disabled for a certain role/user?

Comment: Also second question, can you make it hidden for certain roles/users and not for everyone?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to hide the item - to hide an item do this

[image: hide image]

So basically give the item read access as you have done, but then mark the top item you want hidden as hidden

Comment: You should not leave answers that just expand on a previous answer.  You should leave the full answer of how the user would solve the problem.  Also it's probably an unspoken rule, but if an answer is missing something, its better to leave a comment suggesting what can be done to that answer to make it better.