# Can I exclude items that the current user doesn't have Read access to from display in the Content Tree?

Tags: editor-user-permissions

I have removed *Read* access to some items for certain a *Role*. The problem is that I can still see the items that I removed access to in the tree, when logging in as a (non-admin) user with the role that I denied *Read* access on.

[image]

When I click on the item that I removed *Read* access to, I get a "selecting item could not be found" error message.

[image]

Some of the users on this site are only allowed access to a specific sub-tree/set of pages, which makes the display of these items without read access and the popup message pretty jarring.

Is there any way for me to exclude items that the current user does not have *Read* access to from display in the Content Tree?

**UPDATE:**

Note that I did not *explicitly* deny *Read* access to the items, but rather removed the existing read access from inheritance, so that the access is denied, by default.

**Version Used:** Sitecore 8.1.2

***Before you mark this as a duplicate, please note...*** I have read [this similar post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/396/423) but the only answer does not support multiple roles, where one (with read access) should see the items in the tree and another (without read access) should not. Based on the comments on the [one answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/398/423) provided, I believe that the question was originally asked differently and then clarified to be similar to mine, which may have resulted in less attention and fewer answers being posted.

Comment: I just tested this to confirm.  Removing read access should remove it from the tree in a clean instance.  Do you have just one CM server?  Did you try clearing the caches?

Comment: @BenGolden Tried clearing the caches to no avail. Items are still showing for the test user.

Comment: I used 8.1 update 3 since I already had an instance of that running.  I'm pretty sure this functionality didn't change between updates 2 and 3, but I can  spin up an instance update 2 in a few minutes.

Comment: Yep, I see the same behavior in 8.1 update 2.

Comment: I see the expected behavior that the item does not show in the content tree when read access has been removed.

Comment: I'm filing a support ticket, in case this is something that I managed to break on my own.

Comment: Maybe you have a role which is override the read access

Comment: If so, why would the Access Viewer show that the user doesn't have read access, @HishaamNamooya?

Comment: On the access viewer you will not see which role is overriding other role. But when items are being loaded this is when the roles are being overriden

Comment: @HishaamNamooya, I just tested by explicitly denying read access to an item for a new user with only the sitecore\Author role. Same issue: item still shows and I get the pop up. Can't be an overriding role :/

Comment: Silly question, but your test users aren't also marked as Administrators are they?

Comment: Not a silly question at all, @RichardHauer. I don't mind people asking me if it's plugged in ;) To answer your question, no, they aren't marked as administrators. I also spun up a clean instance and replicated the exact same security configuration, but couldn't reproduce the issue, though I can reproduce it on another (non-clean) instance of the same site. As such, I think this must be a solution issue

Comment: I'm on a train which limits what I can test, but I would use JustDecompile to step through the Sitecore method that applies the security and see what's going on. That's faster than random experimentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, there is actually a Sitecore setting that controls whether or not Sitecore should check security on each node when rendering the tree. If set to false, all nodes are shown and the error message that I described in my post is displayed if/when a user tries to open an item they do not have read access to.

```
<!--
  CONTENT EDITOR CHECK SECURITY ON TREE NODES
            Determines if the content editor checks the security settings on subitems
            when rendering the tree. Setting this to false may increase performance.
            Default value: true.

-->
<setting name="ContentEditor.CheckSecurityOnTreeNodes" value="true"/>
```

While the default value of this setting is true, in my case it turns out that one of the devs disabled this setting for sake of performance on their local environment and accidentally committed the change.

Comment: I had exactly this issue. This is quite an annoying side-effect of this change. We could do with a setting of how many levels deep to go or instead only for children of collapsed nodes and not the parent item it'self.

Comment: @AdamSeabridge I totally agree. I ran a quick reference search, and (as expected) it doesn't look like there is a way to tap into the code that uses this setting to custom implement that. I think that would be a great, low-effort feature suggestion for an upcoming Sitecore release.

Comment: +1 for that :-). It seems a shame to have one setting that applies all the way down the tree instead of controlling at what level it applies.